# Windows Calculator shortcut keys

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, calculator

I'm using the calculator to solve equations like this:

```
((2 * 2.12) *  (0.657)) - ((3 * 2.97) *  (0.657^2))
```

where `(0.657^2)` is 0.657 squared.  However, if I run that in the calculator, the `^` is used as the bitwise OR function and not the power funtion.  I tried finding a list of shortcut keys for the calculator, but all I could find was a small list that didn't include what I want to do!  Does anyone know where I could find a list of all the shortcuts for the calculator? (e.g., `p` = Pi, `^` bitwise OR, `*` multiply, etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a power, press the letter "Y" in Windows Calculator.  For example, the keystrokes "0.657y2" (without the quotation marks) will show up on the calculator interface as:  0.657^2

Visit the [Shortcut Keys Page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts) for a full list.

Comment: If you're looking for the Calculator shortcut keys: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13805

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation

> ((2 * 2.12) *  (0.657)) - ((3 * 2.97) *  (0.657^2))

which results in -384320691 can be rewritten as

```
2 * 2.12 * 0.657 - 3 * 2.97 * 0.657 ^ 2
```

All the parentheses are redundant: power has the highest precedence, followed by multiplication, addition comes last.

If you replace `^` by `y` you can just copy'n'past it into the calculator, the return key gives the result, alternatively you can add the equals sign before the transfer, like in the following line:

```
2 * 2.12 * 0.657 - 3 * 2.97 * 0.657 y 2 =
```

As to speed-up casual calculator usage, it pays off to learn a few keyboard shortcuts, the most important for every-day use are

- **0 ... 9** for the digits
- **decimal point `.`**
- usual operators **`+`,`-`, `*`, `/`**
- parentheses **`(`,`)`**
- **`=`** or ***Enter*** key giving the result

Other shortcuts that do a great job for me include **`n`** for the natural logarithm (the combination with `n/2n` gives me the dual logarithm, mostly I have to hit enter before that). Also helpful are **`Esc`** for the **C** button or **`Ctrl`+`M`** store (**MS**) and **`Ctrl`+`R`** recall (**MR**).

### Be careful

There are some false friends like `^`, because these are ignored and turn 2^20 silently into 220, so be careful, to not confuse the windows calculator with your favourite programming language.

The official documentation is included here (no direct anchor avail):

[Keyboard shortcuts in Windows apps - Windows Help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13805/windows-keyboard-shortcuts-in-apps)

Another ref (in case Microsoft moves their content without adding a redirect):
[Windows 7 Calculator Keyboard Shortcuts - printable cheatsheet](http://www.shortcutmania.com/Windows-7-Calculator-Keyboard-Shortcuts-printable-cheatsheet.htm)

### Finally

The probably least helpful Shortcut is `F1`, because it misses to even mention that there are keyboard shortcuts. (This seems to depend on the Windows version, as I recall that this changed from Win XP to Win 8.1)